# Don't do something on specific input

Tags: javascript

```js
input = window.prompt()
x = true

if (input.includes("stop working")) {
    if (x = true) {
        console.log("not working")
    }
    x = false
}

if (x = true) {
    console.log("working")
}
```

Theoretically, when I enter `stop working` into the window prompt, it shouldn't log `working`, but when I enter `stop working` it logs `not working` and then `working` even though `x` is `false` and it should only log `working` when it is true.

Comment: this code shouldn't even be working.  You're not using any `;` at the end of your statements  and the `=` is used to assign values while `==` or `===` is used for comparing them.

Comment: @optiq you don't need `;` on every statement - it's quite common for people not to use them - some standards even enforce not using them - https://standardjs.com/rules-en.html#semicolons - also see https://blog.izs.me/2010/12/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding

Comment: oh... nvm then lol.

Comment: @Emusaurus, make sure you write code properly and with constancy. This will help you spot *dumb* mistakes — *as I like to call them* — way more easily as you get better at programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `if(x=true)` you're passing a **default parameter** to `x`, so it's always be true, the correct in this case, is:

```js
input = window.prompt()
x = true

if(input.includes("stop working")){
  if(x == true){
    console.log("not working")
  }
  x=false
}

if(x){ // here
  console.log("working")
}
```

If your intention, is to **compare variables**, you have to use `==` or `===`, like this:

```js
input = window.prompt()
x = true

if(input.includes("stop working")){
  if(x == true){
    console.log("not working")
  }
  x=false
}

if(x == true){ // here
  console.log("working")
}
```

**But**, in this case, you variable is a boolean, so you don't need to do this comparison in the `if`.

And if you want a more **otimized code**, you can do this:

```js
input = window.prompt()

if(input.includes("stop working")){ 
  console.log("not working")
} else {
  console.log("working") 
}
```

Comment: The variable x is a boolean, so he needs to use it as: 

input = window.prompt()
x = true

if(input.includes("stop working")){
  if(x){
    console.log("not working")
  }
  x=false
}

if(x){
  console.log("working")
}. ` == ` is comparing objects not values

Comment: You do not even require the input variable if you really want to get down to the optimised code. A shortcut `console.log(window.prompt().includes("stop working") ? "not working" : "working")` would sufice.

Comment: He can do this: `x == true`, it's weird, but he can. And I already add one more code, where he don't need the inner `if`

Comment: @Lain yes, the idea is just clarify that have a better way comparable with the original, but there's thousands of differents way to do this.